# Can I give power 5V 2.1A to Raspberry Pi 3 B+?

Tags: power, power-supply, pi-3b+

I have already taken RPI 3 B + from post office and now I want start RPI 3 B +. But I'm seeing that I haven't got 5V 2.5A Power Block. So, I have a question.
Can I give power 5V 2.1A to Raspberry Pi 3 B +?
Please, help me and say can I do it?
Best Regards,
Mammadli Elnur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be okay. I use my Pis headless (without keyboard and display) and use any 5V supply I can find.

Comment: Okay, But How can boot the OS to it if I shouldn't use keyboard??

Comment: And can I use HDMI and connect it to TV??

Comment: As Joan says. Disable Bluetooth to save a little power.

Comment: HOW????????????

Comment: I suggest you try and find a different power supply if it doesn't work.

Comment: @TheFnafException have you actually tried to use your power supply?

Comment: @TheFnafException joan is not telling you that you shouldn't use a keyboard and display. It was just an example of a particular use-case. Like joan, I use any power supply I can find, and even when I need a keyboard/monitor (which is rare), it works just fine.

Comment: @TheFnafException To disable Bluetooth set `dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt` in `/boot/config.txt` and execute `sudo systemctl disable hciuart`.